# Why inspect.signature() gives incorrect signature about object.__new__() method?

Tags: python, python-3.x

According to [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html):

> The inspect module provides several useful functions to help get
> information about live objects such as modules, classes, methods,
> functions, tracebacks, frame objects, and code objects.

I tried to get the signature of `object.__new__()` method.

The inspect gives me this:

```
inspect.signature(object.__new__)
<Signature (*args, **kwargs)>
```

So it seems at least 2 args can be provided.

But when I tried below code (A is predefined class):

```
object.__new__(A, 1)
```

Below error arose:

```
TypeError: object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate)
```

It seems the `inspect` module gives a wrong signature?

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature) contain a note: "Some callables may not be introspectable in certain implementations of Python. For example, in CPython, some built-in functions defined in C provide no metadata about their arguments." I guess this happens here.

Comment: Thanks. This just adds even more mysteries to the peculiar OOP design of Python...